# What algorithm to use to count realization of high combinatorics setup?

Tags: algorithms, combinatorics

I'll use the MobA games to illustrate what I'm asking since it's easier to explain even tho I want to apply that algorithm to time series.

In a MobA game you have more than 100 characters and every game involves 5v5 with 10 different characters. So it's 10 choose 100 meaning there are 17,310,309,456,440 possibilities.

What I would like to do is use a database with millions of games and work out probabilities for 10-characters setups to come up. Since players will often choose the same characters the high combinatorics won't stop multiple games from having the same setup in a pool of let's say 1 million games.

However given the high combinatorics I can't just make a table with all possibilities and put every new game setup to a case. How should I proceed?

I've been thinking to maybe create a case with first game checked, and then for each new game either higher the count of that first case or create a new case if it's doesn't correspond and so on. Is that the most efficient way to proceed?

Comment: See: [sampling a random combination (en.wikipedia.org)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Probability:_sampling_a_random_combination), [question on math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175942/sampling-a-combination-randomly), and [reservoir sampling (en.wikipedia.org)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling). As for preventing duplicates, you will have to maintain a whole list of all "game setup" you have chosen. See also [orthogonal array testing (en.wikipedia.org)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_array_testing).

Comment: Perhaps someone could write a better answer if you provide more details, especially whether you are only interested in generating completely random (with equal probability) samplings, or some application-specific preference that is not equal-probability.

Comment: @rwong I think i've said it but maybe it's unclear, I want to read the historical database of already played games that contains let's say 1million games and see what setups of 5v5 people effectively choosed. So it's gonna be a non-equal-probability, the goal being to see what are the most choosen compositions. I'm not generating anything just reading and sorting.